# SQLite.swift: Can't retrieve table count due to unrecognized token: ":"

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to retrieve a count of records in a table using SQLite.swift and Swift in a Cocoa macOS application. According to the [README](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift), this can be achieved using the following:

```
let users = Table("users")
...
let count = try db.scalar(users.count)
```

However, when this code is executed (from a button click event handler), the following exception is thrown:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: unrecognized token: ":" (code: 1): file...

The offending code is the `db` access line below. The `db` object is assigned with a `Connection` object returned from a separate `Database` struct function when the view loads. I believe this is valid and unrelated as other areas of code are using the same method to open connections to the database successfully.

```
let login = Login()
var db : Connection?
...
let count = try! db?.scalar(login.table.count)
```

Here's the query expression it produces. In text, this appears to be `SELECT count(_:)(*) FROM login`.

[image]

However, interestingly, if I use the following line, the correct result is returned.

```
let count = try! db?.scalar(“SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login”)
```

The model for this `Login` object is:

```
import SQLite

public struct Login {
    let table = Table("login")

    // Bunch of properties for various record fields
    init() {}
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to have been an issue in `SQLite.swift` itself, as I suspected. I found the following `SQLite.swift` issues on GitHub reporting this issue a few days ago.

- [App crash in Xcode 10.2 & error: unrecognized token: ":" - 894](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/894)
- [Invalid SQL statements with Xcode 10.2 - 888](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/888)

The issue was the following, as described by the reporter, [tanzolone](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/888#issue-422799695):

> In Xcode 10.2 beta 4 the macro#functionshows a different behaviour. As
>   SQLite.swift relies on #function in different subroutines for the
>   composition of SQLite queries, several bugs linked to invalid SQLite
>   statements seem to be introduced.
>
> I have just run the SQLite.swift tests with Xcode 10.2 beta 4 and
>   there are several failures linked to this issue.
>
> An example as follows:
>   In the following helper function (Helpers.swift line 107):
>
> ```
> func wrap<T>(_ expression: Expressible, function: String = #function) -> Expression<T> {
>     return function.wrap(expression)
> }
> ```
>
> when called from
>
> ```
> static func count(_ star: Star) -> Expression<UnderlyingType>
> ```
>
> the value of the function when running in Xcode 10.2 beta 4 is
>   `count(_:)` instead of `count`. This leads to invalid SQLite
>   statements of the type `SELECT count(_:)(*) myTable`.

The project maintainers have now resolved this issue at the latest `HEAD` of `master` (currently [1a908a7da11852f252e7c6b6366a4d9f8a7d5272](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/1a908a7da11852f252e7c6b6366a4d9f8a7d5272)).

In my project, the line which required updating was the following in my `Podfile`:

```
pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git', :commit => 'ed8f603f856e9f1f4adb76b63b7234547257ec5a'
```

This was updated to:

```
pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Alternatively, one can reference the commit itself:

```
pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git', :commit => '1a908a7da11852f252e7c6b6366a4d9f8a7d5272'
```

To update this reference, I took the following CLI steps in my project root to remove, update, and install the projects pods:

```
$ pod cache clean --all
$ rm -rf Pods/
$ rm Podfile.lock
$ open -a Xcode Podfile   # Updated the SQLite.swift project ref to the above
$ pod install
```

This then resolved the issue and the exception is no longer thrown.